# I can't print, is the data not inserted or is there something wrong in the loop?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I need to make some storage record, I need to be able to insert, see the data, and search according to an id (I haven't reached the search part yet). My problem is either the data not recorded, or it couldn't be printed both of them due to indexing problem imo. what do I need to do?

```
struct item{
    char *name;
    int qty;
}item [10];

int main ()
{
 int i=0,n,menu;

 printf("Goody Storage\n");
 printf("=============\n");
 printf("Input Storage[1..10]: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 for(;;i++){
  if(n<=10){
   printf("\nGoody Storage\n");
   printf("=============\n");
   printf("\n1. Add Items\n");
   printf("2. See Items\n");
   printf("3. Search Items\n");
   printf("4. Exit\n");
   printf("Choose Menu[1..4]: ");
   scanf("%d",&menu);
   switch(menu){
    case 1 :
     printf("Input name of item %d: ", i+1);
     scanf("%s",&item[i].name);
     printf("Input qty of item %d: ", i+1);
     scanf("%d",&item[i].qty);
     continue;
    case 2 :
     printf("\nNo.\tName\t\t\tQuantity\n");
     printf("========================================\n");
     printf("%d\t%s\t\t\t%d\n", i, item[i].name, item[i].qty);
     continue;
    /*case 3 :
     printf("\nInvalid Choice");
     continue;*/
    case 4 :
     return 0;
    default :
     printf("\nInvalid Choice");
   }
  } else break;
 }
}
```

Comment: You never seem to use `n` anywhere in your code, after that `scanf` call?

Comment: Also, the structure has a pointer `name`, but it will be `NULL` for all structures in your array. Perhaps you should make it an array as well?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&item[i].name);` --> `scanf("%s",item[i].name);`

Comment: Your indexing is out of sync with everything. What is `i`? What is `n`? At the moment, you increase `i` with every menu choice, even invalid ones. And since you read into `item[i]`, you should test whether _that_ (and not `n`) is smaller than (and _not_ smaller than or equal to)  your maximum storage, 10.

Comment: @MOehm My guess is that `n` is supposed to be the array index. And that there's no real need for `i`. Together with the problem pointed out by Keine Lust and about the pointer-member pointed out by me earlier, that's probably the bulk of the problems the OP have.

Comment: Or `i` is the actual size of the array and `n` is the max size. (That's why there is a test for `n`.)

Comment: Actually reading the code closer, it seems the OP have misunderstood the assignment. There should be an infinite loop (without any counting or variable incrementing). Then in that loop you should show the menu: If you want to add an "item" you do it at the next free position in the array (you need to keep track of this). You should not select an "item" before the loop, and only work with that "item".

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps back, read the assignment again, talk to your teacher, teachers assistants (if any) and your class-mates. Let the teacher clarify what you're unsure about. Then sit down and think about how to implement it, write down a list of requirements, do a simple design, and then come back to the code. And write not all of it at once, but small pieces that you can easily test and debug.

Comment: thank you for your comments, I forgot to specify the i and the n haven't I? Variable i is meant to be the actual index of the array, while n meant to be the max amount. and yes, the menu should be in infinite loop. The table will contain max 10 rows. I think I need to redo it per functions